# Ckeditor update textarea

Tags: textarea, ckeditor

I am trying to get the ckeditor working. Obviously it doesn't make use of the textarea so on submit the form doesn't submit the text in the editor. Beceause I make use of polymorphic associations etc. I can't make a onsubmit function to get the value of the textarea (when the form is submitted) .

So I found this question: [Using jQuery to grab the content from CKEditor's iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924145/using-jquery-to-grab-the-content-from-ckeditors-iframe)

with some very good answers. The answers posted there keep the textarea up to date. That is very nice and just what I need! Unfortunately I can't get it to work.
Does somebody know why (for example) this doesn't work?

I have a textarea (rails but it just translates to a normal textarea):

`<%= f.text_area :body, :id => 'ckeditor', :rows => 3 %>`

And the following js:

```js
if(CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor ) {
  CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor);
}
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor',
{
skin : 'kama',
toolbar :[['Styles', 'Format', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Link']]});


CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].on("instanceReady", function()
{
//set keyup event
this.document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);

//and paste event
this.document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
}

function CK_jQ()
{
 CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor.updateElement(); 
}
```

I get the following "error" in my firebug. 

`missing ) after argument list
[Break on this error] function CK_jQ()\n`

Comment: Ok so of course there is an error in the code above. there is a ) missing :P (but still not working though

Comment: please change title to Ckeditor 4 update textarea

Answer (score 55, accepted):

have you figured it out?

I'm using CKEditor version 3.6.1 with jQuery form submit handler. On submit the textarea is empty, which to me is not correct. However there is an easy workaround which you can use, presuming all your CKEditor textareas have the css class *ckeditor*.

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
   var $textarea = $(this);
   $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
});
```

Execute the above before you do your submit handling ie. form validation.

Comment: Same solution for prototype: `$$('textarea._cke').each( function(T) { T.update( CKEDITOR.instances[T.id].getData() ); } );`

Comment: @TJ- I am new in Jquery, I dont know how it works ? Could you please write a line of code that alerts the value of ckeditor ? i am trying with :- `alert($textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData()));` . Please...

Comment: @J.J. Before you alert assign the jquery object of your textarea to $textarea. `var $textarea = $('textarea.mytextarea');` Then use `alert(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData())`. Do this after the ckeditor has been applied.

Comment: I think you have to use $textarea.html() instead of .val()

Comment: getData() and val() work perfectly fine, but see answer by sldev where he uses CKEDITOR's updateElement().

Comment: after loading editor by replace, you may add this line >>>   CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaClientId.on('blur', function(){CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaClientId.updateElement();});

Comment: I had to use:
$('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
   var $textarea = $(this);
   $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('id')].getData());
});

The instance was named by the fields ID not name.

But it seems a more supported solution as mentioned above by Ben Amada is:
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
             CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();

Comment: Just in case anyone reading this needs to do it for FCKeditor, the cases are different:  `$(this).val(FCKeditorAPI.Instances[this.id].GetData());`

Comment: This is quite useful if you want to Encode the HTML before it goes into the textarea

Answer (score 122):

Before submit do:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
```

Comment: But the OP already calls updateElement all the time and it still didn't work for OP, that's possibly why this isn't the answer here.

Comment: @Nenotlep: the accepted answer is basically the same but is a workaround for my answer since CKEDITOR already provides that with updateElement

Comment: @sldev: I agree that your solution is better, I was trying to point out that he already called updateElement() in his solution, although in a not so logical as your place before submit :)

Comment: Works great. What beats me is why CKEditor's default save action does not work this way.

Comment: Don't forget `if (CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(instanceName)) {`

Answer (score 10):

Combination of all of the above answers into one.

Create a new custom.js file and add this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
  $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {

    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("instanceReady", function() {
      this.document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);
      this.document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
      this.document.on("keypress", CK_jQ);
      this.document.on("blur", CK_jQ);
      this.document.on("change", CK_jQ);
    });
  });

});

function CK_jQ() {
  for ( var instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) { CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); }
}
```

You don't have to worry about the name of the textarea, just add a class `ckeditor` in the textarea, the above and you are done.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @JohnDel for the info, and i use onchange to make it update every change.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
   $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change", function(e) {
        for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    });
   });
});
```

Comment: I wish CKEDITOR did this by default, i can't really see any reason not to?

Comment: `instanceReady` is triggered for every editor instance that you have. So if you have multiple instances *this will bind the `onChange` event multiple times* doing a lot of unnecessary work. Instead of the `$.each(...)` you should use make use of [the event parameter](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#event:instanceReady) that is provided to the `instanceReady` callback and take its `editor` attribute which is the editor instance that has just called its `instanceReady` event.

Comment: This one also works on multiple textareas, loaded by ajax and using CKEDITOR.replace('item', language).

Answer (score 6):

ADD Function JavaScript for Update

```
function CKupdate() {
  for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

It's work. Cool

Answer (score 2):

Just Add

```
CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaClientId.on('blur', function(){CKEDITOR.instances. textAreaClientId.updateElement();});
```

where `textAreaClientId` is your instance name

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].on("instanceReady", function()
{
//set keyup event
this.document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);

//and paste event
this.document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I just increase that to the response of T.J. and worked for me:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    $('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
       var $textarea = $(this);
       $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On load:

```
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    function CK_jQ(instance) {
      return function () {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
      };
    }

    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (instance) {
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("keyup", CK_jQ(instance));
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("paste", CK_jQ(instance));
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("keypress", CK_jQ(instance));
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("blur", CK_jQ(instance));
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change", CK_jQ(instance));
    });
  }, 0 /* 0 => To run after all */);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been some API changes with the latest versions of CKEditor, so here's an answer for CKEditor 5:

```js
let ckeditor;

// Create a CKEditor, and store its handle someplace that you may
// access later. In this example, we'll use the `ckeditor` variable:
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector("textarea"), {})
  .then(editor => { ckeditor = editor; });

// When your form submits, use the `updateSourceElement` method
// on the editor's handle:
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  ckeditor.updateSourceElement();
});
```

To my knowledge, CKEditor does this automatically when you submit a form, so this particular example shouldn't actually do anything. But it is useful when you need the content of the textarea to udpate without submitting the form that contains it.

Answer (score -2):

All above answer are focusing on how to fix this error but I want to take the answer on what cause me this error

I had a

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" rows="6" name="Cms[description]"></textarea>
```

changed to

```
<textarea class="ckedit" rows="6" name="Cms[description]"></textarea>
```

I changed class attribute value to anything other than **ckeditor** and boom error gone.

Hope that help