# get the value of fck editor in JS

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, fckeditor, zend-form-element

I would like to get the value of FCKeditor in javascript for client side validation.
The name of FCKedtor is 'article_des'.

I am trying to get value like below, but when i change the value of fckeditor then this code is not reflecting the new values entered in fckeditor.

`alert(document.form_edit.article_des.value);`

Its alerting old value.

My html code for FCKeditor:-

```
echo $this->formFckeditor('article_des',html_entity_decode($this->data['article_des']),array('size'=>'30','maxlength'=>'75'));
```

Actually i want to check that the value is not blank because its a required field.

How can i get the value in JS ?

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of FCKEditor are you using? You may find this post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147670/ckeditor-update-textarea/7079054#7079054

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('article_des');
alert(oEditor.GetXHTML(true));

//OR
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('article_des') ;
var pageValue = oEditor.GetHTML();
```

Hope it helps