# The validation rule is not applicated to the field when using CKEditor with Symfony2 Form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, ckeditor, field

As in the title, I Don't know why when I applicate CKEditor class to my Symfony2 Field Form as follow:

```
->add('contentCours', null,array(
    'label' => 'Content: ', 
    'attr' => array('class'=>'ckeditor')))
```

If the Form is submitted, I will got an SQL exception telling me that the colomun `content_cours` can't be null!

But that won't happen when I remove the CKEditor class atrri from the field...

I don't know what the wrong with that really, am I messing somthing?
THanks for your help :)

Edit: To be more clear, I want the following => Don't subbmit the form if the "contenctCours" field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your CKEditor updates textarea field and correct POST request sent on form submit. This also may help ["CKeditor update on submit post"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147670/ckeditor-update-textarea)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...To be honset am not too good with Js and JQuery, I tried the solution you suggested but it doesn't work for me, the problem is always remaining...

Comment: anyway, it seems, that its frontend problem, not backend one

Answer (score 0):

In my case CKEditor didn't sent POST data because of wrong type of field, i had `<input>` field but CKEditor needs to use `<textarea>` to save the POST data, so i had to change the field type from `null` or `TextType` to `TextareaType`.

Dont forget to import the class:

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

Example:

```
->add('contentCours', TextareaType:class, array(
    'label' => 'Content: ', 
    'attr' => array('class'=>'ckeditor')
))
```