# Setting form values from fckeditor before submit is called

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I'm trying to fix a form on a site that uses javascript to validate the fields.

Some fields are using fckeditor, and it turns out that the form field values aren't set until the submit button is pressed - rendering my form validation useless.

What I want to do is (hopefully) just call a method in fckeditor to update the form values it's tied into.

Does anyone know of such a method?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation at [FCKeditor 2.x / Developers Guide / JavaScript API](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API#Retrieving_an_Editor_Instance)

```
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('InstanceName').UpdateLinkedField()
```

for CKEditor <sup>from [Using jQuery to grab the content from CKEditor's iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924145/using-jquery-to-grab-the-content-from-ckeditors-iframe/2007427#2007427)</sup>

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```