# How to get value of a textarea which is controlled by a javascript html editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I am trying to write a code which allows my website users to save drafts. I am facing a problem while doing this.

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="SAVE DRAFT" onClick="saveit()">
<textarea id="content" name="content" class="widgEditor nothing">initial text</textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
function saveit() {
   var content = $('#content').val();
   alert (content);
   //some other ajax codes to save draft... 
}
```

When I click the `Save draft` button, it always shows `initial text` even if I change the text in the textarea (editor).

I have tired this with widgEditor and CKeditor but unfortunately I could not figure out how to fix this problem.

NOTE: When I try this without any WYSIWYG editor, it works properly but that text area needs to be an editor.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: By the way, I have found this jquery plugin which exactly does what I want.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/CKEditor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably help if you use CKEditor:

[Using jQuery to grab the content from CKEditor's iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924145/using-jquery-to-grab-the-content-from-ckeditors-iframe)

Essentially, you use this before you read the value:

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```

Also I think you should use .text(), not .val() when working with textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onClick`

```
$(':button').click(function() { 
    var content = $("#content").val();
   alert( content );
   //some other ajax codes to save draft...  
});
```

works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/KEtMC/